# Support of ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS} in email after promoted-build?

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, promoted-builds

I use Jenkins (v1.578) with promoted-build (v2.19) and mail-ext (v2.38.2) plugins.

I would like to use the ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS} in an email sent as an Action after the promotion succeeded.

At the moment I get a blank value for ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}, I suspect this is related to the way the promoted-build plugin work (seems to create a new job for the promotion which does not have any changes)

Is it possible to use a specify key or even use the groovy template to retrieve data from the original build ?

**EDIT:** My final goal would be to notify some people that a new release has been deployed in the staging environment, idealy the email should contain all the changes since previous deploy (=Since last success).

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of: at the end of the build, echo the value of `${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS}` to a file, and archive the file with other build artifacts.

Then when running the promotion, bring the artifact over as you would other artifacts (Copy Artifacts plugin), and read it's value

Comment: Interesting idea, any experience with this? Any chance this value could be accessed via the groovy templating system provided by mail-ext ?